# New thunderbolt MacBook Air and external monitors

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt

Does the MB Air with thunderbolt only connect with Apples Thunderbolt monitor?
What are the options for third party monitors with DVI or VGA?

Answer (score 5):

They're the same as for other computers with Thunderbolt:

- DVI/VGA/HDMI with cheap passive Mini DisplayPort adapters (audio is included over HDMI, assuming your adapter supports it)
- dual-link DVI with a more-expensive active Mini DisplayPort adapter
- any native DisplayPort monitor (many mid-to-high-end monitors already have them)
- any Thunderbolt monitor (all one of them currently announced)

You can use any Mini DisplayPort adapter that you might already have, or any that are available for purchase. I have my brand-new 2011 MBA hooked up with a Monoprice MDP->DVI adapter right now.

Answer (score 2):

The MB Air has a Thunderbolt port but you can also just plug in a Mini DisplayPort with an adapter to a pretty much any monitor or TV you want. You can use a number of adapters such as Mini DisplayPort -> DVI or HDMI.

[Mini DisplayPort to DVI](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=104&cp_id=10428&cs_id=1042802&p_id=5106&seq=1&format=2) on Monoprice

[Mini DisplayPort to DVI](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB570Z/A) on Apple Store