# How do I connect my MacBook Pro 15" (2011) to an HDTV?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, thunderbolt, hdmi

I just bought a brand new MacBook pro 15-inch model with highest specifications in this June. It is running 10.7 Lion.

How do I connect my MacBook to HD TV? It looks like it has only the "Thunderbolt" connection for "Apple" monitors.

---

So should I buy this (first variant):

1. [http://store.apple.com/uk/product/H1824ZM/A/Moshi_Mini_DisplayPort_to_HDMI_Adapt er?fnode=MTY1NDA3Ng&mco=MjI2OTg1MTU&s=priceHL](http://store.apple.com/uk/product/H1824ZM/A/Moshi_Mini_DisplayPort_to_HDMI_Adapt%20er?fnode=MTY1NDA3Ng&mco=MjI2OTg1MTU&s=priceHL)
2. and this http://store.apple.com/uk/product/MC838ZM/A?fnode=MTY1NDA3Ng&mco=MTk0MjUwOTU&s=priceHL

or just the second variant:

[http://store.apple.com/uk/product/H2775ZM/A/Mini-DisplayPort-to-HDMI-Cable-5m?fn ode=MTY1NDA3Ng&mco=MjA4MDc2MDY&s=priceHL](http://store.apple.com/uk/product/H2775ZM/A/Mini-DisplayPort-to-HDMI-Cable-5m?fn%20ode=MTY1NDA3Ng&mco=MjA4MDc2MDY&s=priceHL)

P.S.: this writes

> "Use to connect your Mac with Mini DisplayPort - Mac mini (Video only),
>   MacBook (Post May 2010), MacBook Pro (Post March 2010) to a TV or
>   Monitor with HDMI connections"

So does that mean that it is not suitable for 2011 MacBook Pro model?

Comment: A list of adapters that work from Thunderbolt to HDMI is here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23584/what-adapters-work-from-thunderbolt-to-hdmi

Comment: also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19098/new-thunderbolt-macbook-air-and-external-monitors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bought the adapter from Apple to get the HDMI output from my MBP (same as yours).  You can visit the Apple Store for the adapters - I bought one of each adapter available, as I wanted to be prepared for whatever need I came across.  The Thunderbolt port is to be used with the adapters.

I also both several different lengths of HDMI cables.

My TV has several HDMI input ports.  The MBP automatically recognizes the TV as another monitor, so the only effort left is to get the TV setup to use that HDMI port as the Source.

Comment: Could you please post the link of the actual adapter you bought for yourself?

Comment: I bought both.  You really want to know which I use, and I can't tell you that until I use it.  I have only used an adapter for this purpose a couple of times in the past two years.  see bmike's response below.

Comment: I got the $15 version from Microcenter, and spent the difference on beer.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to check out [Monoprice](http://www.monoprice.com). They have a ton of adapters, cables and other accessories, which in my experience have all been of good quality, for much cheaper prices.

They have the specific [MiniDisplayport or Thunderbolt to HDMI Adapter](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=104&cp_id=10428&cs_id=1042802&p_id=5311&seq=1&format=2) you need for under $7. They've got a pretty extensive collection of cheap HDMI cables to go along with it as well.

Answer (score 2):

Any video adapter that is either a Thunderbolt adapter or a mini Display Port adapter is designed to work when plugged into any Thunderbolt mac.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the thunderbolt protocol is Display Port (the next gen video interface standard like VGA and DVI) and has a mini display form factor that any mini display adapter can fit into. This means you can pick up a minidislpay port to HDMI adapter and use that. IF you need HDMI cables, apple sells really nice 1.8meter long ones for like $18

tip: if you use an external monitor, i suggest a mini display pot to DVI adapter, and then just use a DVI to HDMI adapter when needed

Answer (score -3):

Just got to Walmart. I bought a thunderbolt to HDMI adapter and it worked perfectly.

Kind of stupid if you ask me since their new MacBook Pro models have HDMI.

Comment: Link to the adapter you bought!